# How to change row's id value of <Datagrid /> with other attributu's value

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

`<Datagrid />` component seems automatically set id of each row to `id` attribute of a record

this is my records:

```
[
   {
      id: "d28dda00-a835-4fb2-956d-b70b168fc2ab",
      name: "Harry Potter",
      price: "10",
      sale_id: "a92dda11-7bfb-414e-a757-0051aad2fc5b",
   },
   {
    ...
   }
]
```

If we select the checkbox we can see in `selectedIds` attribute like this

```
['d28dda00-a835-4fb2-956d-b70b168fc2ab']
```

instead of using `id` attribute I want Datagrid to use `sale_id` as row's id

so the result would be like this:

```
['a92dda11-7bfb-414e-a757-0051aad2fc5b']
```

How can I do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You may create a function to map `sale_id` to `id` for each record before passing data to the `Datagrid` component.

```
const saleIdToId = (data) => {
  return data.map(record => ({
    ...record, id: record.sale_id
  }));
};
```

Then inside your App pass

```
const newRecords = saleIdToId(records);
```

to `Datagrid` component.